# How to block implicitly casting from `any` to a stronger type

Tags: typescript, casting, tslint, any

TypeScript allows implicitly casting from `any` to a stronger type.  Considering deserialized JSON is of type `any`, this behavior allows many type errors and breaks typings.

What compiler or linting options can I use to block implicitly casting from `any` to a stronger type?

**Repro** This operation should be flagged for allowing casting from `any` to a stronger type.

```
const o = JSON.parse("");
const s: string = o.twinlakes;
```

Comment: As soon as you choose to work with `any`, you get this behaviour. The solution is to create a type for the JSON data. For example: `const o : Test = JSON.parse("")`. If you really don't know the contents of the JSON data you'll have to write code to determine the JSON content. I wouldn't recommend working with unknown data throughout a project.

Comment: Yes that is the motivation for this question.  I want to use an automated system to flag anyone choosing to work with `any` in our code base.

Comment: In your example, Typescript and TSLint think everything is fine, since you apparently WANT to work with `any`. (Since `JSON.parse()` explicitly sets `o` to the `any` type). I would also like some kind of warning for this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you haven't yet, try enabling the TypeScript [`--noImplicitAny`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/noImplicitAny.html) compiler flag to stop declarations from accidentally forgetting to mark types of things that can't be inferred. This'll stop code such as `function takesData(data) { /* ... */ }` from allowing their `data` variables to "implicitly" be type `any`.

*Edit January 2023: the correct answer is now to use [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io):*

Additionally, there are several ESLint rules from typescript-eslint you can use for `any`s that can sneak in even with `--noImplicitAny`:

- [`@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-argument): Disallows calling a function with a value with type any.
- [`@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-assignment): Disallows assigning a value with type `any` to variables and properties.
- [`@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-call): Disallows calling a value with type `any`.
- [`@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-member-access): Disallows member access on a value with type `any`.
- [`@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-return): Disallow returning a value with type `any` from a function.

You can enable those rules individually in your ESLint config to use them in your project. Alternately, they're all enabled if you extend from the [`plugin:@typescript-eslint/strict` configuration](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/configs#strict).

Finally, as Titian mentions in the comments, consider using `unknown` in your code in any place you'd have wanted to use `any`. `unknown` is similar to `any` but TypeScript will enforce that you properly [type narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) `unknown` values before using them unsafely.

---

The answer below is outdated because [TSLint is deprecated](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534). Please see above for the answer with [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io).

Additionally, there are a couple [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint) rules that help here:

- [`no-any`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any): Disallows usages of `any` as a type declaration. Use this to stop declarations from including `any` in them, e.g. `let data: any = {/*...*/}`.
- [`no-unsafe-any`](https://palantir.github.io//tslint/rules/no-unsafe-any/): Disallows accidentally using `any` in an unsafe way. This is different from `no-any` in that you might still be using `any` types without knowing it: for example, `let data = JSON.parse("{}");`.

Comment: And use `unknown` anywhere you would use `any`

Comment: I currently already have "tslint:recommended" and "tslint-react" rule sets.  I just added "no-unsafe-any" explicitly and see no change when casting properties of an `any` object to `string`.  I believe `noImplicitAny` in `tsconfig.json` is already blocking the use case of `no-any`.

Comment: `noImplicitAny` does not block using the `any` type. It only blocks _implicit_ `any`s, meaning ones that aren't declared as type `any`. Functions whose parameters are not given an explicit type definition, such as `function foo(data) {}`, are implicit. The `let data: any` above is explicit.

Comment: I just added a repro case to the original question.  I tried adding `no-any` and `no-unsafe-any` to my tslint rules, but it is not flagging any of the code.

Comment: Your repro case is very similar to some of the test cases for `no-unsafe-any`, so it definitely should be flagging it. This is probably either a TSLint bug (if so, file an issue on TSLint please!) or because your lint command isn't linting your file.

Comment: After further investigation, I think this is a VSCode TSLint extension bug (not TSLint).  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ooh! This might help: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/blob/master/tslint/README.md#how-can-i-use-tslint-rules-that-require-type-information

Answer (score 0):

In additiona to Josh's answer, since the type check takes place during runtime, you can try using the '`as`' keyword to cast the value from '`any`' to the type you want.

```
const o = JSON.parse("{\"twinlakes\":\"Value\"}");
```

const s: string = (o as any).twinlakes;

How that works